# Chord progression notation

Tags: notation, chord-progressions

from [here](http://www.teoria.com/reference/c/cadence.php)

At the top - right under  "The perfect authentic cadence. V (dominant) - I (tonic)", in second measure, 
they have "6 over 4 over V" on first two beats and then "7" on 3rd beat...

What happens in this measure?? Why is not there Roman numeral under 7??

Answer (score 2):

In figured bass notation thirds and fifths are implicit in root position chords. Therefore, if you just see a "7", this means R, 3, 5 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the 7 concerns also the dominant. You have two different chords for the same function.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question. I think this is indeed a mistake in the notation, if my music theory isn't too rusty.

The first two beats of the second measure are indeed clearly a tonic (I 6over4), considering that the notes are dbdg. And only on the third beat it becomes the dominant (be it dominant seven). The V should indeed be on the third beat under the 7.

I think the correct notation would be:

1..2..3..|1..2..3..|1..2..3..||

I..6..ii6|I64...V7.|I........||